# Pseudoinverse computation using VBA and C++ DLL

Tags: excel, vba, armadillo, blas, matrix-inverse

I want to pseudoinverse a big degenerate matrix using VBA in Excel (analog of wide-known "pinv" function). As I understand excel tools can't deal with degenerate matrices.

I found nothing better than try to implement a C++ DLL library and link to VBA. I faced following problems:

My configuration is: Windows 10 x64, Office 16 x64. I create DLL with VS 2015 as x64 DLL. I have managed to create and link simple DLL and even pass to and get from Double Arrays. But when it came to use math libraries such as Armadillo with dynamically linked BLAS, a mess arose.

Any working and debugged code which uses BLAS x64 DLL in case being wrapped as DLL and invoked from VBA crashes Excel. I already checked dependencies and put BLAS/LAPACK dlls into almost every suitable folder. It crashes even I don't use any passed parameters.  Proc monitor shows that dependencies are ok. It looks like when Excel calling some function from the DLL prevents external calls from that DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a little late and not exactly what you asked for but i just finished writing a VBA subroutine which calculates the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of a matrix which might still be helpful to you. It follows similar processes to MATLAB's "pinv" function and produces comparable results. You can get the code from the link below. There's also a comparison between results of the VBA and MATLAB functions summarised in a table.

http://www.nicksfinancetricks.com/index.php/2017/01/08/moore-penrose-pseudoinverse-calculation/

There are three main components to the algorithm, these include QR Factorisation via Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalisation, Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), and finally the removal of any Singular Values so the pseudoinverse can be formulated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put any required dll in the same folder of your .xlsb (or .xlsm) file, and have an auto_open with the following code:

```
Sub auto_open()
    With ThisWorkbook
        ChDrive .Path
        ChDir .Path
    End With
    ....
End Sub
```

This makes the current folder the first one to be searched for called dlls.

As another suggestion, I think you might use openblas, an optimized blas which includes lapack also, with some of lapack routines optimized. You may find version already compiled as "OpenBLAS-v0.2.14-Win64-int32", which includes the precompiled dll libopenblas, plus the required dlls libcc_s_seh, libgfortran and libquadmath. There is no pre-canned pseudoinverse. but you may have a look at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1606150, which tells you how to implement it, maybe even in vba.